# Create a JSON Array from dynamic values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, dynamic-arrays

I need to create the array like `{"groupslist":{"groupname":["user1","user2","user3"],"groupname2":["user1","user2","user3"],"groupname3":["user1","user2","user3"]}}` which the values are get from the different ajax call to the server, in first ajax call i get the grouplists like groupname, groupname2 etc and in the success function i make  the ajax call for each groupname and get the user for the particular groupname and create the array and push that to main grouplist, The output am getting is not correct i think i have to use some callbacks to make it correct, please help me and tell me `

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_group_list',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        groupnamess=data.replace("[","").replace(/"/g, "").replace("]","").split(',');
        console.log("groupnameeeee",groupnamess);
    for(var i in groupnamess)
    {
     grup[i]=groupnamess[i];
     userss.push({
            label:groupnamess[i],
            value:groupnamess[i]
          });
    grupss.push(groupnamess[i]);
    }
    for(var i in grupss)

    {
        console.log("geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",grupss);
        console.log("geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",groupnamess[i]);
         $.ajax({
            url: 'get_user_list',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{'name':groupnamess[i]},   
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("55555555555555555555"+data);
                if(data!='[]')
                {
                    //addy.substr(0, addy.indexOf('.')); 
                    var group=groupnamess[i];
                    console.log("cccccccccccccccccccccc"+group);
                    grouplist[group]=new Array();
                    console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"+data);
                    var usrs=data.replace("[","").replace(/"/g, "").replace("]","").split(',');
                    for(var j in usrs)
                    {
                        grouplist[group].push(usrs[j]);
                        console.log("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"+usrs[j]);
                    }
                    console.log('ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo', grouplist);
                    var grp=$.parseJSON(grouplist);
                    consoloe.log(grp);

                }
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log('error', errorThrown);
            }
        }); 
        console.log("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    }   
    users=userss;
    console.log("gupppppppppppppppppp"+grupss);
    console.log('success', users);
    },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
     console.log('error', errorThrown);
    }
});`
```

output is

> ```
>  groupnameeeee ["user00", "super user", "supreme user"] myjs.js:35
> geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ["user00", "super user", "supreme user"] myjs.js:48
> geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee user00 myjs.js:49
> eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee myjs.js:80
> geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ["user00", "super user", "supreme user"] myjs.js:48
> geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee super user myjs.js:49
> eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee myjs.js:80
> geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ["user00", "super user", "supreme user"] myjs.js:48
> geeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee supreme user myjs.js:49
> eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee myjs.js:80
> guppppppppppppppppppuser00,super user,supreme user myjs.js:84
> success 
> [Object, Object, Object]
>  myjs.js:85
> 55555555555555555555["sample_vh.com"] myjs.js:55
> ccccccccccccccccccccccsupreme user myjs.js:60
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa["sample_vh.com"] myjs.js:62
> rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsample_vh.com myjs.js:67
> ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo 
> Object {supreme user: Array[1]}
>  myjs.js:69
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o myjs.js:70
> 55555555555555555555["veera_tls.com","v_v.com","sample_vh.com"] myjs.js:55
> ccccccccccccccccccccccsupreme user myjs.js:60
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa["veera_tls.com","v_v.com","sample_vh.com"]
> ```
>
> myjs.js:62
>       rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrveera_tls.com myjs.js:67
>       rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrv_v.com myjs.js:67
>       rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsample_vh.com myjs.js:67
>       ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo 
>       Object {supreme user: Array[3]}
>        myjs.js:69
>       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o myjs.js:70
>       55555555555555555555[]

Comment: So what is data in this line? `3. success: function (data) {` Its always odd to do string manipulations on stringified JSON.

Comment: What the hell's going on here: `groupnamess=data.replace("[","").replace(/"/g, "").replace("]","").split(',');`

Comment: You just need to specify the dataType: 'json' and you will get an object as the first argument in the success handler.

Comment: how i can get the groupname values(user1,user2,user3) from the grouplist object using the jquery@NULL

Comment: how i can get the groupname values(user1,user2,user3) from the grouplist object using the jquery@Andy

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your code.

Just create the array and pass that array to `JSON.stringify` to JSONify it.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
JSON.stringify(arr); // "[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'get_group_list',
    type: 'POST',
    async:false,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {
        groupnamess=data;

    for(var i in groupnamess)
    {
     grup[i]=groupnamess[i];
     userss.push({
            label:groupnamess[i],
            value:groupnamess[i]
          });
    grupss.push(groupnamess[i]);
    }
    for(var i in grupss)

    {

         $.ajax({
            url: 'get_user_list',
            type: 'POST',
            async:false,
            dataType:"json",
            data:{'name':groupnamess[i]},   
            success: function (data) {
                if(data!='[]')
                {

                    var group=groupnamess[i];

                    grouplist[group]=new Array();

                    var usrs=data;
                    for(var j in usrs)
                    {
                        grouplist[group].push(usrs[j]);

                    }


                }
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log('error', errorThrown);
            }
        }); 

    }   

    users=userss;
    console.log('successddddddd', users);
    },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
     console.log('error', errorThrown);
    }
});
```